# Create a body div using CSS

Tags: css, custom-background

I am trying to add a white background to just the body and header text on my blog, so that I can add a background image behind the whole site.

I know I need to create a div that sits behind the body and header, however I'm a beginner with CSS so could do with a few pointers if possible.

Blog address is [www.astridkearneyblog.com](http://www.astridkearneyblog.com)

Any help would be greatly received!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest Solution would be to create a new css rule that simply changes the background color of an element to white i.e:

```
.white-background{
   background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Then just add `class="white-background"` to the elements you want to have a white background. Just remember an HTML element can have multiple classes inside a single class="" attribute just add the classes separated by spaces.

if you add this class and the background doesn't behave you can add !important to the CSS rule as follows:

```
.white-background{
   background-color: #ffffff !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to place the elements above and below each other

Check out Mozilla and W3Schools for an intro to CSS, and if you're really serious about getting into making websites, Team Treehouse has great curriculums

If you didn't make the theme you're using, check out the theme options page. It might have an option to add a background image

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/
- http://teamtreehouse.com/